# How to get remaining percentages for column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table formatted like the following, we'll call it "Payments"

```
P_ID | P_PayNum | P_AmtPerc | P_Type
1    |    1     |   100     | FP1
2    |    1     |   50      | 2P1
3    |    2     |   50      | 2P1
4    |    1     |   25      | 4P1
5    |    2     |   0       | 4P1
6    |    3     |   0       | 4P1
7    |    4     |   0       | 4P1
```

The question with the table I am working with, I am trying to come up with the best way to **create an UPDATE script using @TempTables and inserts** to find all values where a AmtPerc = 0 and figure out how to take the current non-0 (in this case the 25 for 4P1 type) and figure out the remaining from the 3 that are 0 (which would all be 25; 25*4 = 100).

There are a couple of entries in this table with payment plans of quarterly, semi-quarterly, semi-annually, bi-monthly, etc. Those same few also suffer from an issue where only the first partial-percent is present (the 1st payment) and the rest are 0. So I am trying to find the best way to dynamically find all the 0's, find the 1st payment that represent that set and have it update those to the correct percentages that would total to 100.

*I am honestly unsure of how to word this any better and hopeful someone understands what I mean.
If there is a better way to phrase or parse this question, then feel free to modify it to make more sense and maybe the code discovered can help someone else with figuring out remaining partial percents totaling to 100.*

Comment: does the P_AmtPerc always = 100 for P_Type = FP1, 50 for 2P1, and 25 for 4P1 ??

Comment: Ideally the refcodes represent the type of payment. Full Payment would only need one payment, so it would be expected that 100% payment be due. 2P1, two payments, with the first being 50% down and the remaining 50% due at a later date. Etc :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At sounds like you want to not just compute the missing payment percentages, but also to update the base table with them.  In SQL Server, you can accomplish that this way:

```
UPDATE p
SET p.P_AmtPerc = r.remaining_perc / r.num_zero
FROM
  payments p
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
        P_Type,
        100 - SUM(P_AmtPerc) AS remaining_perc,
        SUM(case P_AmtPerc when 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_zero
      FROM payments
      GROUP BY P_Type
      HAVING SUM(P_AmtPerc) < 100
        AND SUM(case P_AmtPerc when 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
    ) r
    ON p.P_Type = r.P_Type
WHERE p.P_AmtPerc = 0
```

You will recognize the inline view as similar to the queries presented in the two other answers posted so far.  It computes for each payment type the percentage remaining to be allocated and the number of payment rows among which to split it, filtering out any payment types for which (at least) 100% payment is already allocated, or for which there are no rows with zero payment specified.

The rest of the query is proprietary SQL Server syntax for, basically, updating a table via a view.  It updates only those rows that have `P_AmtPerc = 0` **and** have a corresponding row in the inline view.  In particular, if there is a payment type whose recorded payments add up to at least 100, but that also has some zero-percent payments, then now rows for that payment type are updated.  It ignores any non-zero payment percentages, splitting the balance among the zero-percent payments instead of making them all match the first payment.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used or seen a HAVING clause where I work. Beyond that tiny bit of off-topic notice, I will say that your solution worked out incredibly well! I will end up choosing this as the best answer for the current situation, because it did exactly what I was asking about! :)

Seriously, all the answers were great and each could've led me to the correct, but this one did directly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a moment to wrap my noodle around this one, you have different payment codes (at least for this example), but when all payments for a given code are made the percentage should equal out to 100%.

What you want is to find unpaid payments, where at least one payment has been made, and figure out how much is left to pay.

```
Select AccountNumber --I imagine this will be replaced by an account PK or item PK
  , 100 - sum(P_amtPerc) as RemainingPercent 
  , sum(case when P_amtPerc = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as RemainingPayments
From Payments
Group By AccountNumber --Once again this is a stand in for your real PK
having sum(P_amtPerc) < 100
```

What this does is we use a group statement to allow us to aggregate the rest of the table, in this case we want to see how many payments are yet to come, and what percent is left. We use the having clause to filter out accounts that are fully paid (eg: 100%), so we are sure we are looking only at accounts with payments outstanding, or partial payments. Hopefully that's on the right track for you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
create table #temp (P_ID int, P_PayNum int, P_AmtPerc int, P_Type nvarchar(5));
insert into #temp values (1,1,100,'FP1');
insert into #temp values (2,1,50,'2P1');                    
insert into #temp values (3,2,50,'2P1');
insert into #temp values (4,1,25,'4P1');
insert into #temp values (5,2,0,'4P1');
insert into #temp values (6,3,0,'4P1');
insert into #temp values (7,4,0,'4P1');

select  A.P_ID
       ,A.P_PayNum
       ,A.P_AmtPerc
       ,A.P_Type
       ,case when T1.cntpct = 0 or A.P_AmtPerc > 0 then 0 else (100-T1.sumpct)/T1.cntpct end as Remainder
from #temp as A
join (select    P_Type
               ,sum(P_AmtPerc) as sumpct
               ,sum(case when P_AmtPerc = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as cntpct
from #temp
group by P_Type) as T1 on
T1.P_Type = A.P_Type;
drop table #temp;
```

Comment: Though not the selected answer, this was still a great answer! I might use some of the techniques for the joins and temp setup for future tasks :) Thank you